# Laravel Homestead access

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, laravel-5, homestead

Recently I've discovered Laravel Homestead and thought I'd give it a try. But as of now, every guide/tutorial I found uses **ssh** with it, making you bound to use a terminal window.

Simple question: is there a way to access Laravel Homestead apart from ssh? Maybe visually?

A good advantage of developing locally is using your own preferable IDE or text editor, and it seems I can't do that with Homestead. I can't just open a virtual machine window and use it's Ubuntu graphical features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What gives you the idea that you can't develop locally under Homestead? Homestead is simply a [Vagrant box](https://www.vagrantup.com/). And Vagrant - by its very nature - is intended to allow you to develop locally under a shared directory. So you absolutely CAN develop locally with Homestead, or any other Vagrant environment.

Answer (score 0):

when you use homestead you will have  a synced folder in a path that you choose 
(
for exemple `C\:code`
everytime you change that code it will change in the vagrant box too 
so you still can use your best IDE
)
why using homestead? its the best way to have everything that you need without downloading and configuring lots of things (i think)